# Visual basic 6.0: function returning array

Tags: arrays, function, vb6

Is there better way how to create function returning array than:

```
function foo
 Dim bar(1 to 2)as double
 bar(1)=1
 bar(2)=2
 foo=bar
end function
```

and in code:

```
arrayx=foo
```

Because when I declare `Dim arrayx(1 to 2) as double` it throws an error "can't assign array" When I don't declare the variable arrayx it doesn't seem to have any problems.

Comment: You forgot to specify the return type of your function.

Comment: Cody: If I knew how to specify it I would do so. When I tried to do so I obtained only error messages.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As [Matt suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055888/visual-basic-6-0-function-returning-array/6055948#6055948), this error:

> Compile error: Can't assign to array

stems from the fact that you've tried to assign the return value of `Foo()` to a *fixed* array, rather than a dynamic array. You simply need to indicate to the compiler that the variable you're declaring is an array, not the actual size of the array. It will figure out the size based on the size of the array that is returned.

Additionally, you should always specify a return value type for your functions. You do that in VB by placing an `As Type` clause at the end of the function declaration. In this case, you want an array of doubles, written as `Double()`.

So, rewrite your code to look like this, incorporating both of those changes:

```
Function Foo() As Double()      ' note the specification of a return value
   Dim bar(1 To 2) As Double
   bar(1) = 1
   bar(2) = 2
   Foo = bar
End Function

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Dim arrayx() As Double       ' note the declaration of a DYNAMIC array
   arrayx = Foo()
   MsgBox arrayx(1)
End Sub
```

This code displays a message box with the value "1", just as expected.

Comment: Thanks for giving a right code and explaining what I did wrong.

Comment: what if you want to return ALL the items in the array in the message box?

Comment: @Jason You need to loop the array (with LBound and UBound) and build a string with the message to be returned.

Answer (score 2):

[You can only assign to a dynamic array](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186423). Try:

```
Dim arrayx() as Double
```